# How to align button on bottom when used with file uploader and label aligned on top?

Tags: javascript, css, file-upload, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using filefield for file uploading and i am placing an upload button besides it.
when placing long labels its layput is breaking and upload button is placed at top.
I want my label aligned to 'top'
How can align the button to bottom.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                bodyPadding: 1,
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    autoSize: true,
                    align: 'bottom'
                },

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    labelSeparator: '',
                    fieldLabel: 'When placing long labels the layout is breaking and the upload button is placed at the top.',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    buttonText: 'Select',
                    flex: 1                        
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Upload',
                    width: 50
                    //,margin: '22 0 0 2'
                }]

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From HTML markup I see that this issue is caused by layout. It sets top position of `filefield` to 259px and `button` to 278px. It assumes that label has only one line. Easiest fix is to set height of label element in css to 33px (2 lines).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VphZH/1/

Another possibility is to extend `filefield` and add another button to it. Then it should be more layout independent.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VphZH/3/

Comment: when i am trying second method. i am getting error on this  line me.callParent(arguments); error is : 'fileInputEl.dom' is null or not an object. - on render function in file ext-all.js

Comment: I can'tt reproduce this error. My examples are working, so maybe you have some issues with layout?

Comment: can you please comment on this code.  if (Ext.isIE) {
                me.uploadButton.getEl().repaint();
            }//what it is for. i have some IE rendering issue. displaying border when I hide a panel

Comment: This is adapted code from original `Ext.form.field.File.onRender` method, so I am not sure what it does. Probably it fixes some issue on IE, but I don't know what exactly :)